# How to find Image contains specif image/Logo

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, android-image, google-vision

I have image with size of 36*36 it's logo of company .every time my app capture image, I want to find is that logo is available. if its available need to find it coordinates in the image. Guide me in right direction

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Feature Detection on your logo
2. Feature Detection on your image
3. Match feature descriptors
4. Compute a good homography with RANSAC (assuming the logo is planar)
5. Logo is found when number of inliers is above a threshold
6. The coordinates of the logo in the new image can be found by projecting a rectangle with your homography

EDIT:

This tutorial has some sample code: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html

Comment: Can u elaborate little more, i could not get what your mentioned  above.

Comment: I found a tutorial that does exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the code .. but i need it in java so is there any link for java or do i need to implement same using java and opencv ?

Comment: I don't know of any java implementation of this, so you probably have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use template maching with rescale of image: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

For example you run template maching for a image at original resolution and for 3 - 4 rescale with 1.1 and for 3 - 4 rescale with 0.9.

Resize: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: I am checking on the examples of opencv

Comment: I have tried open CV example in android phone.. it keep on crashing.

Comment: What crashing? I don't understand. You have openCV installed, no? If you use camera try `System.gc();` for calling garbage collector.

Comment: I used Open CV first thing it ask me to install OpenCV apk in device . After i did it keep on crash i used YU Mobile with 5.1.0 android OS